# PHP: Storing custom field values in a record

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a basic CMS system using PHP and MySQL.  I've run into a roadblock where I want the ability to create a custom field on a record.

Creating the field was easy, the issue I'm having is adding the custom field to the array which is sent in the mysql query.

Here's what I tried so far.

```
if(Input::exists()) {
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {
        try {
            $record->create('test_record', array(
                foreach ($cust_field->results() as $val) {
                    $val->{'Field'} => Input::get($val->{'Field'}),
                }
            ));

        } catch(Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I know now that using a foreach loop inside an array doesn't work.  But I can't seem to find anything that will work.

Comment: Why not do it the other way around? Add the values to the array first, then create the record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
if(Input::exists()) {
  if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {
    try {
        $fields = array();
        foreach ($cust_field->results() as $val) {
            $fields[$val->{'Field'}] = Input::get($val->{'Field'});
        }
        $record->create('test_record', $fields);

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```